# Expression.Call on static method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I am currently having the exception bellow and I can't figure what the issue is. Initially I had the update function as a local method and the exception actually made sense, but I since then moved to become a static method but the issue is the same. Any help is welcome. Thanks

**Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance site:stackoverflow.com**

```cs
public virtual Task<int> UpdateAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereFunc, Func<T, T> updateFunc, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    return InitializeQueryable(new ExtendedQuery<T>
    {
        Where = set => set.Where(whereFunc)
    }).UpdateAsync(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression.Call(Update(updateFunc).Method)), token);
}

public virtual Task<int> UpdateAsync(ExtendedQuery<T> queryProperties, Func<T, T> updateFunc, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    return InitializeQueryable(queryProperties).UpdateAsync(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression.Call(Update(updateFunc).Method)), token);
}

private static Func<T, T> Update(Func<T, T> updateFunc)
{
    return x =>
    {
        var entity = updateFunc(x);

        if (entity is IVersionedEntity versionedEntity)
        {
            versionedEntity.Version++;
        }

        return entity;
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you think `Update(updateFunc).Method` refers to?  It definitely doesn't refer to your `Update` method.

Comment: What is `ExtendedQuery`? What are you trying to invent?

Comment: @KirkWoll you're completely right, late in the day... completely missed it